# Best way to render a partial which requires HAML to be nested under the parial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, partial, nested

I am looking to reuse a form in my webapp, I have tried using a partial to complete this task. Here is the code I am trying to DRY out:

```
#layouts/_form.html.haml
.col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3.well.form-box
  .col-sm-12
    .row
      %h1
        .text-center Create a new trip.
        .small.text-center
        Let's get started planning your trip.

    .row.top-buffer
      = bootstrap_form_for(@trip, url: customers_trips_path) do |f|
        = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object

        = f.text_field :trip_name, label: "What would you like to call this trip?"
        = f.select :location, options_for_select(Vendor.allowed_locations, params[:location]), label: "Where will you be going?"
        = f.date_select :start_date, { :label => "What is the start date for your trip?", :start_year => Time.new.year }
        = f.number_field :number_of_days, value: 1, in: 1...90,  label: "How many days will you be going for?"

        .center= f.submit "Create Trip", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

My partial attempt looked like this:

```
- provide(:title, "Create a Trip")

.col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3.well.form-box
  .col-sm-12
    .row
      %h1
        .text-center= header
        .small.text-center
          = slogan
    .row.top-buffer
```

However, when I try to render my partial like above, then nest my form under it, I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

I'm pretty sure I am doing it wrong. I was looking into passing bootstrap_form_for somehow (possibly using Object#send?), but that seemed a bit heavyhanded, and was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

**UPDATE:** I fixed the call to the locals in the partial, and updated the code to reflect that. Issue still persists.

Here is how I am calling the partial, btw.

```
= render 'layouts/form', header: "original", slogan: "test"
      = bootstrap_form_for(@trip, url: customers_trips_path) do |f|
        = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object

        = f.text_field :trip_name, label: "What would you like to call this trip?"
        = f.select :location, options_for_select(Vendor.allowed_locations, params[:location]), label: "Where will you be going?"
        = f.date_select :start_date, { :label => "What is the start date for your trip?", :start_year => Time.new.year }
        = f.number_field :number_of_days, value: 1, in: 1...90,  label: "How many days will you be going for?"

        .center= f.submit "Create Trip", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

Cheers!

Comment: Your code doesn’t actually show you calling the partial. Can you show the actual code that you are using that is causing the error?

Comment: @matt, done as requested!

Answer (score 1):

As described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html (look for "locals"!), you should use the local passed to the partial as a "real" local, in other words, without ':' attached to it!

Comment: Thanks @Danny. Tried your solution, but the issue persists. I did lead you do not have to pass the `:locals =>` tag though!

Comment: What I normally then do is strip the partial until it works, then build it up again. This normally shows you where it goes bananas... At first sight, the error suggests some 'end' missing...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should change your partial view to following:

```
- provide(:title, "Create a Trip")

.col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3.well.form-box
  .col-sm-12
    .row
      %h1
        .text-center= header
        .small.text-center
          = slogan
    .row.top-buffer
```

Comment: Done, edited OP to reflect this. Issue still persists. Thank you :)